# 'Missing parameter type' in Play template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4, play-templates

I have the following template defined block in Play 2.4.6 (using scala 2.11.6 and sbt 0.13.8) abd I get a "mising parameter type" on the following code:

```
@property(budgetId: Int, propertyName: String, value: String, shouldEdit: Boolean = false, displayMethod: Option[String => String] = None) = {
  <div>
    <label class="prop-name">@displayMethod.getOrElse(String => propertyName)(propertyName)</label>
    @shouldEdit ? editable(budgetId, routes.Budgets.update(budgetId), "input", propertyName, value) : <span>@value</span>
  </div>
}

@editable(id: Int, url: Call, inputType: String, name: String, value:String) = {
    <div class="editable"
        data-editable-input="@inputType" data-editable-url="@url"
        data-editable-id="@id" data-editable-property="@name" >@value</div>
}
```

Anyone has any ideas of why that might be?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the details of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@displayMethod.getOrElse(String => propertyName)` is the problem.

`String` is actually an identifier here, and not the type `String`. So you have some function with a *parameter name* `String`, and the type of it is not known. The compiler will not infer the type to be `String => String`, because `Option#getOrElse` has a type parameter `B >: A`, which means it doesn't have to be `String => String` (just bounded below by it).

You have to provide the type yourself. The clearest way would be to say:

```
@displayMethod.getOrElse((_: String) => propertyName)
```

Now we're declaring a function that is explicitly `String => String`, where the `_` represents the single parameter that we don't care about.